# How to read Custom error message from backend in Angular 4/2

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

```
API

add(data) {
 return this.httpClient.post<any>('/api/v3/templates', data);
}

Observable

this.templateService.add(obj)

.subscribe(
 (response) => { 
  console.log(reposne)
 },
(error) => {
 console.log(error)
 }
);
```

My Post API gives back a error with some Message in response as Name Already Exists But i am not able to get that in error Object which is printed to console

```
The object which is printed is
{
    error:null
    headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, 
    lazyInit: ƒ}
    message:"Http failure response for http://localhost/api/v3/templates: 
400 Bad Request"
    name:"HttpErrorResponse"
    ok:false
    status:400
    statusText:"Bad Request"
    url:"http://localhost/api/v3/templates"
```

}

how can I get the message  that I am getting in response as my error 
    object doesn't have that response body.

Comment: This response says its a bad request  ` status:400
    statusText:"Bad Request"`

Comment: I am getting a response in text with this error  which is not in the error object  and the https statusText is the property contains the text of the response status, such as "OK" or "Not Found"/ BadRequet.

Comment: @atulmishra, have you found solution for this one. I am also trying to send custom error message from server but can't receive it when using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http). However same thing worgs perfectly when I use older [Http](https://angular.io/api/http/Http)

Answer (score 1):

The error returned is normally an instance of HttpErrorResponse, with an `error` property containing the wrapped error (client or server)

https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

So normally you should be able to handle the error like this.

```
add(data) {
 return this.httpClient.post<any>('/api/v3/templates', data)
  .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
  return new ErrorObservable(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
};
```

If the `error` property is null this could be because the server does not return anything. Did you check using postman  or some other tool that your server returns the appropriate response?

Answer (score 0):

In Observable there are three options.

- Next - which you subscribed to get the data
- Error - Its the next function you passed to the subscribe method. It contains the error status code and mostly http error like error in connection, bad request.
- finally - its execute any how after all.

there are others too like map, debounce etc.

```
  this.templateService.add(obj)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {  // this is the next and hold the response
        console.log(response)
      },
      (error) => { // this is the error
        console.log(error)
      },
      (finall) => { // this is final and execute alwasys
        console.log('this is the final piece of code to execute')
      }
    );
```

I think you your case the error might not coming in http standard and might be coming in subscribe.

So check if the customized message is coming in next rather as an error.

Comment: added the code, also fount that in the console.log the spelling of response is wrong, you can correct that

Comment: Still not getting and I was doing the same thing

Comment: @atulmishra Did you find an answer to this question yet?

Comment: @Euridice01 Nope still didnt get

Comment: Passing multiple arguments is deprecated since RxJS 6.4: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments. Rather, an object with next, error, complete properties with function values should be passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [typed response](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular/):

On your `error` notification type you could have something like:

```
err =>  {
        this.localErrorResponse = err as ErrorResponse;
        this.message= this.localErrorResponse.message;
      }
```

before, in your class:

```
import { ErrorResponse } from './error-response';
...
localErrorResponse: ErrorResponse;
message: string;
```

and then, your `ErrorResponse` can be like:

```
import { HttpHeaders} from './http-headers';

export class ErrorResponse{
  error: any;
  headers: HttpHeaders;
  message: string;
  name: string;
  ok: boolean;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  url: string;
}
```

and class `HttpHeaders`

```
export class HttpHeaders {
  normalizedNames: any;
  lazyUpdate: any;
  lazyInit: any;
}
```

then you can map some other variables, as `message` (`this.message`)